# Code compression tool

Tags: html, web

In developement environment we write jsp + html +js code in a clean readable form. But in production it should be compact and without all unessary space.

So what is the best practice adopted to compact the code before going into production. I can't compact in development environment as it will be tough to understand to write code.

What i want is

```
Development code (uncompressed) -> compress before production -> production code (compressed)
```

any tool that will compress all my project files all at one go ?

Most of minifying tool compress js , css files but they are not ideal for 100s of files as they change individually.

Comment: Are you shooting for transmission speed or ... what? You could just configure your server for gzip compression.

Comment: does gzip will remove all unecessory spaces does it produce o/p like a js minifying tool?

Comment: No but it'll compress your whitespace for faster transmission.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [mod_pagespeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module)

> PageSpeed speeds up your site and reduces page load time. This open-source webserver module automatically applies web performance best practices to pages and associated assets (CSS, JavaScript, images) without requiring that you modify your existing content or workflow.

It's quite powerful, and will go beyond just minifying source code and do things like inline images.